# How URL in CSS should reference images in resources folder

Tags: css, maven

I have created a Maven dynamic web project from an archetype.  When it came time to add the javascript, css, and image folders, I put them under the webapp folder, so that the folder structure looks like:

```
myproject
  |
  main
  |  |
  |  java
  |  |
  |  resources
  |  |
  |  webapp
  |    |
  |    css
  |    |
  |    imgs
  |    |
  |    js
  |    |
  |    WEB-INF
  |
  test
```

But then I had second thoughts, because Maven creates the resources folder for images, right?  So, if I put imgs folder under resources, that is outside of webapp... and then how can CSS reference those images?

Or, in fact, is the answer that the resources folder should be under webapp?  (But then, Maven would have created it there, right?)

Answer (score 2):

In your current state you must use url like this :

```
url('./webapps/imgs/ex.jpg');
```

and if you want to move imgs folder into resources try this :

```
url('./resources/imgs/ex.jpg');
```